# Spring Boot Spring Data JPA - Don't scan for Implemented classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've noticed in our spring boot projects that during start up, spring seems to scan the classpaths for an implemented version of each of our DAOs.

We don't currently have implementations of our DAOs. We just extend the JPARepository and let spring data create the daos for us.

Is there any way to tell spring boot not to search for the implementations? We think it may help shave some time off of our start up times.

Comment: It isn't scanning the class path for implementations it is scanning the class path for classes annotated with `@Component` so that it can create instances of it.

Comment: I understand there is time taken to scan for beans. However, on log tracing, we specifically see this:

2018-04-04 09:10:05,680 [main] DEBUG app=xxx, env=user o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Searching directory [C:\dev\java\xxx\target\classes\com\xxx\app\xxx\dao] for files matching pattern [C:/dev/java/xxx/target/classes/com/xxx/app/xxx/dao/**/*UserDAOImpl.class]

This leads us to believe it's scanning the classpath for impl classes to override the default daos, which we don't want to spend time doing as we don't implement these classes at all.

Comment: This doesn't come from Spring Data, it comes from other Spring parts, which scan your classpath for beans, mappings etc.

Comment: This is actually default Spring Data JPA behavior which cannot be switched of (without overriding a great part of Spring Data detection). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior.

Comment: That's unfortunate. This seems to be slowing down our start up times greatly as we have more than 100 daos.